# Javascript OOP: how to refer to object

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following JavaScript object. When the window resizes, I want it to call its own `resize()` method. However, in the `window.onresize` function, `this` refers to `window` - not the Canvas object. How do I call the Canvas object?

```
function Canvas(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.canvas = element.getContext("2d");
    this.width = element.width;
    this.height = element.height;

    this.resize = function () {
        this.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.height = window.innerHeight;

        this.element.width = this.width;
        this.element.height = this.height;
    };

    window.onresize = function () {
        this.resize();
          ^- error
    };
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tried any searches/tutorials for `this` to see *what it really means*? A keyword here is "closure" or "binding", and there are a million variations (of answers and SO questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.onresize = this.resize.bind(this);
```

If you're supporting older browsers, include [the MDN compatibility patch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for `Function.prototype.bind()`.

Comment: @Patrickdev Note that `bind` isn't implemented in IE8 and Safari, so you probably want to shim it.

Answer (score 4):

Save the value 'this' in the scope of the constructor in the closure of the `onresize` handler.

```
var _this = this;
window.onresize = function () {
    _this.resize();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Does exactly what I want, but doesn't seem as clean as 'am not i am's solution.

Comment: Saving this, what a neat idea. +1

Comment: @Patrickdev I actually wish I had remembered his solution, it's much neater. I knew of it but never use it because I tend to do `var $this = $(this)` so often anyway.

Comment: +1, but I"d prefer to use an unambigous variable name. Since *this* should reference the canvas, why not `var canvas = this;`? Then you have `canvas.resize();` so it's much clearer what's happening.

Comment: @RobG True, but for a variable whose scope is all of 4 lines it's kind of a wash.